# Jetpack Compose Material3 TopAppBar container color problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            YourProjectNameTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        MyUI()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyUI() {
    val contextForToast = LocalContext.current.applicationContext

    LargeTopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = "SemicolonSpace") },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                Toast.makeText(contextForToast, "Nav Icon Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu")
            }
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                Toast.makeText(contextForToast, "Add Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add Items")
            }
        },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.3f)
        )
    )
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you can see the the color is not applied to the title. It is applied to icons part only. I also got this problem with medium top app bar too, but not with center and small app bars. Am I doing something wrong? or is it a design guideline?

These are the gradle files I'm using:

project level gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

app level gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.yourprojectname'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourprojectname"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

**Fix:**

There is no fix. The bug is [reported here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250838918). I tried changing versions, using `background()` modifier. Nothing worked. The only solution is to create a custom app bar using `Surface()` or `Box()` composables.

Comment: The containerColor is applied to the title as well for me. Can you provide more info like jetpack compose versions, material versions, devices used, etc?

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thanks for the reply. I added gradle files. I am testing it in the emulators Pixel 3a XL API 28 and Pixel 5 API 31.

Comment: I tried using the provided version, but still not reproducible. Can you try updating the dependencies version or using a different emulator or physical device?

Comment: @Abhimanyu I tried changing version, but nothing is working. I decided to create custom app bar using Surface().

Answer (score 0):

Try newer version of Material 3, I am using material 3 versions `1.0.0-alpha11` and it is working:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha11'
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Strange. I added the same version, but still I have the problem. I decided to create custom app bar using Surface().

Comment: Still, the Issue occurred in "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha11"

Answer (score 0):

Try newer version of Material 3, I am using material 3 versions 1.1.2 and it is working:

```
 implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
```

result:
[image: result]