# Android Compose LargeTopAppBar containerColor not apply

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

LargeTopAppBar uses ContainerColor to apply the desired color when the AppBar is fully expanded.
However, container color only applies to the default AppBar color.

Is there anything I set up wrong?

```
@Composable
fun CollapsingToolbarScreen(){

    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
    val isCollapsed: Boolean by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            scrollBehavior.state.collapsedFraction == 1f
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = { LibraryTopBar(scrollBehavior, isCollapsed) },
    ) { innerPadding ->

        LazyColumn(
           modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ){
            items(count =50) {
                ListItem(
                    text = { Text(text = "Item $it") },
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
                            contentDescription = "Favorite",
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun LibraryTopBar(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior, isCollapsed: Boolean) =
    LargeTopAppBar(
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
        title = { Text(text = "Library") },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            scrolledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            titleContentColor = if (isCollapsed) {
                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
            } else {
                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
            },
        ),
    )
```

[largetopappbar container color not apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Y7R.gif)

Comment: This code works for me. I have seen a similar question in StackOverflow . It may be device-related or Compose version related. Can you try with different device or emulator or by using different compose version?

Comment: The similar question for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76496388/9636037

Comment: Related issue in issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/250838918

Comment: I saw this question, and adding the same version didn't solve the problem 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2

Comment: This seems to have been fixed with the latest version coming out. 
I was using "androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00".
Applying version 2023.01.00 fixed this issue.